# DVD burner that support DVD players

Tags: gratis, linux, optical-media, closed-captions

I want to burn the entire 24 seasons for a friend on DVDs + Arabic subtitles so he can watch them on his DVD player.

Requirements are simple:

- Free, not necessarily open source
- Supports all kind of DVD players, old and new
- Do not mess up the Arabic subtitles files
- Work on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a DVD authoring software like **[Bombono DVD](http://www.bombono.org/)**:

- free for Linux
- subtitles support
- transcoding video if necessary
- find it in Ubuntu Software Center ([here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bombono-dvd) is the Launchpad page)

[image]

Comment: I feel lucky to have asked the question, I wasn't going to, I thought any cd burner would do, never heard of authoring DVD software before :) Thank you, I will try it and get back to you

Comment: should I choose PAL/SECAM or NTSC, sorry for the naive question :)

Comment: @Fischer that depends on DVD player and TV standard. See http://countrycode.org/tv-standards

Comment: Bombono DVD keeps crashing nowadays, i don't know why, maybe some bug, you have another software in mind?

Comment: @Fischer see [DVD Styler](http://www.dvdstyler.org/en/)